# Why Wash-sale rule makes a difference?

Tags: united-states, taxes, stocks, wash-sale

I have been reading the wash-sale rule. I get the concept, but I do not get why this rule exist or needed. To me, in the end, a person would pay the same amount of taxes with or without create artificial losses.

**Case 1 (trigger wash-sale rule)**

```
Day 1: Buy 10 ABC stocks for $10 per share
Day 2: Sell 10 ABC stocks for $5 per share
Day 3. Buy 10 ABC stocks for $5 per share
Day 4. Sell 10 ABC stocks for $20 per share
```

In case 1, even though it looks like this person created artificial losses on day 2 ($-50), but since he bought at a lower cost basis on day 3, he would need to pay more taxes on the sell on day 4 ($150). The taxes this person would pay on in total is -50 + 150 = 100.

**Case 2 (does not trigger wash-sale rule)**

```
Day 1: Buy 10 ABC stocks for $10 per share
Day 4. Sell 10 ABC stocks for $20 per share
```

In case 2, this person did not trigger the wash-sale rule, and only buy at day 1, and sell at day 4 ($100). The taxes this person would pay on in total is 100.

In these 2 cases, they pay the same amount of taxes on. Even though, case 1 looks like he claimed an artificial losses, but if you look at the bigger picture, he would need to pay more taxes on his second sell than if he would have not sell on day 2. In the end, the math adds up to the same. I didn't get why IRS has this wash-sale rule. Am I missing something?

Comment: The difference is when Day 4 happens in a different tax year than Days 2 and 3. It could even be years later.

Comment: @ThePhoton Even it's the years later, the taxes adding up remain the same.

Comment: Not if you consider time value of money. $10 right now is more valuable than a promise to pay $10 at some (undefined, in this case) time in the future.

Comment: A more important consideration is that the loss I generate today can be used to offset ordinary income (up to $3000/year with carry-forward) which might be taxed at 25% or higher, while the gain I eventually take may be long-term and taxed at capital-gains rates of 10% or 15%.  Tax on $1 is not always the same depending on the income source.  By creative (and *completely legal*) use of this rule, I can shift some of my income to a much lower tax rate and save myself money.  The wash sale rule forces me to take some risk (or use capital) while doing this.

Answer (score 6):

Your wash sale example only has an impact if Day 3 and/or Day 4 are in January of the following year. If this all happened in June, there is no impact, you are right. If Day 3 or 4 are in January then the loss is disallowed for the prior tax year and is pushed to the next tax year or whatever tax year the open position is disposed of. A loss this year is typically worth more than a loss next year to the investor, and tax revenue now is typically more valuable than tax revenue later to the IRS.

If the losses were allowed with no offsetting gain in the current year, they could be used to offset ordinary income (up to $3,000 and rest carried over), while maintaining the same position.

The wash-sale rules don't prevent people from harvesting losses strategically, they just make it so you can't do it without risk of the market changing. They really do just limit the artificial losses.

Answer (score 3):

The wash sale rules exist to discourage people from selling a security solely for the tax loss when they fully intended to continue holding that security.

Comment: I think the question is *why* they want to discourage it.

Comment: Sure. But, to IRS point of view, they receive the same amount of taxes in the end. So, I didn't get why they care even if people intended to do that.

Comment: A primary reason for the wash sale rule is to stabilize stock prices by discouraging short-term speculation.  Stock market rules are designed to be PRIMARILY for investing, not speculating on short-term fluctuations in price.  That said, I speculate that this week would be the WORST week to sell any stock.

Comment: The IRS doesn't want allow tax losses if you rebuy within 30 days.  That's all.  It's got nothing to do with market stabilization, this has everything to do with booking a loss when you buy right back in to the same security.

Comment: if that were true, why would the Emergency Economic Stabilization Act of 2008 include stricter enforcement for tracking wash-sales ?

Comment: @KeithKnauber Sure, I would accept if that's the reason. But if you search on the internet for wash-sale rule, all of the articles are saying it is to prevent people creating artificial losses, which I do not agree.

Comment: @user926958 which you do not accept?  Neither of your examples even include a time period longer than the wash sale 30 days.  I've had plenty of securities over the years that I wanted to continue holding, but on December 31 they were at a paper loss.  But for the wash sale rules I would sell that security, take the loss for the year, and immediately buy it back.  The wash sale rules would force me to top up my cost basis and negate my tax benefit from the loss, so I don't do it, because there's no point.

Comment: @KeithKnauber In your case, when you immediately buy it back, your cost basis is lowered, so even you claimed the initial loss, you will have to pay more taxes when you sell the second batch. In the end, you pay the same taxes on. That's why I don't get why IRS even bother to put this rule.

Comment: The IRS bothers with it because they need you to pay your capital gains taxes this year.  20 years from now when you finally sell for good, a 50% capital loss from this year will be worth almost nothing to the IRS due to inflation.

Comment: @user926958 It's the rule that causes you to owe the same in taxes.

Comment: @KeithKnauber wash sale is about taxes not market stability.  There are HFT firms transacting hundreds and thousands of times a day.  All kinds of superfluous things are attached to bills when they're in congress.  Wash sale rules are about taxes, that's all.

Comment: I can also see how the extremely rich could manipulate an illiquid market (in the very short term) to create capital losses for themselves.  It would probably be very costly for them to do so, but less costly than paying taxes.

Comment: To prevent big players from destabilizing illiquid markets

Comment: @KeithKnauber feel free to write an answer about how a "big player" would be able to destabilize an illiquid market if it wasn't for the tax deferral of wash sale rules.

Comment: For instance: Randolph and Mortimer each own 1M shares of small cap stock XYZ, and the stock is down 50% for the year.  Randolph enters a series of 100k share sell orders.  Stock drops 3% further.  Mortimer buys most of those shares on the way down.  The next day, Mortimer does the same thing for Randolph.  (The scheme would probably need to be much more sophisticated than that).

Comment: Right, like I said, feel free to write an answer.  Wash sale is a tax issue.

Comment: If the cost of executing a scheme is less than the 18% capital gains tax, then its worth it to execute the scheme.

Comment: Write an answer.  What you think you're explaining has nothing to do with wash sales.

Comment: @Keith Knauber. The intent of the wash sale rule is to prevent  investors from churning their positions and claiming the benefit of short-term losses. They want revenue now not later.Discouraging short-term speculation and market stabilization is not the intention or  responsibility of the IRS. If Randolph and Mortimer (nice reference) are buying large blocks of shares from each other, share price is not going to move since there is no net volume order imbalance. If the volume is imbalanced and each 100k share lot drives price down further, the buyer is losing money. It's not a winning plot.

Comment: With the step up in basis for your estate, there is no guarantee the IRS would reclaim a prior loss, should you hold unto death

Comment: Without the wash sale rules there wouldn't be a step up in basis, there would only be your deduction against income which definitely reduces your tax burden this year. The wash sale rule causes the cost basis adjustment.  Without the wash sale rules everyone would sell all their paper losses at the end of the year to book the tax deduction, then immediately rebuy the positions. The wash sale rules require you be subjected to 30 days of market changes before you rebuy the potition if you want to take the tax loss, otherwise you adjust your basis and get no immediate tax deduction.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.law.com/thelegalintelligencer/almID/900005499988/Recent-Ruling-Revisits-Wash-Sale-Rules-in-Internal-Revenue-Code/?slreturn=20190212001817

"The wash sale rules of Section 1091 are intended to limit the ability of taxpayers to generate “paper” losses. Taxpayers should be aware that the IRS is taking an expansive view of the application of these rules and the use of related entities to avoid the wash sale rules will be scrutinized."

...

"However, the IRS relied, exclusively, on the decision in Security First National Bank of Los Angeles, where a taxpayer sold bonds to a corporation of which the taxpayer was the sole shareholder and on the same day the corporation transferred the bonds to a trust over which the taxpayer had absolute dominion and control."

Furthermore, here's an example court case involving wash sales that were used to **destabilize an illiquid market**:

https://law.justia.com/cases/federal/appellate-courts/F2/834/262/33006/

Just because a law is difficult to enforce doesn’t mean it’s not the law.  https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/7/6c

Tax loss harvesting, on the other hand, is a perfectly legal and widely used strategy.

It is legal to sell (for example) an index ETF to harvest a tax loss, and immediately buy different ETF(s) that represent the same index.

Comment: So your second link is a reversal of a trading commission's ruling against someone named Manning Stoller for wash sales in the context of commodities futures where wash sales in those markets are actually disallowed, it's not simply a tax issue in the context of commodities futures markets as there are concerns of actual physical deliveries and the link you provided is a reversal of the decision anyway.

Comment: Just because a law is difficult to enforce doesn’t mean it’s not the law.  https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/7/6c

Comment: I didn't make any sort of comment about whether or not something was the law.  I'm saying you have only an extremely light grasp of what's going on and used an appellate reversal as a citation to prove your point.  This question is about the taxation of wash sales from the perspective of the IRS, this is the context of the lions share of discussion surrounding wash sale rules.  The IRS rules about wash sales have zero to do with market stability.  You found a rule in commodities markets that also uses the term wash sale and seem to think they are the same thing.  They're not.